# What completely determines an homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to an arbitrary group G.

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

I'm trying to determine the monoid $End(Id_{Grp})$, and in particular I need to know what is needed in order to completely determine an homomorfism, say $\phi$ from $\mathbb{Z}$ to an arbitrary group $G$. In case that $G$ is abelian, is enough to know $\phi(1) = g$ because $\phi(n)=g^{n}$ is an homomorphism because $\phi(n+m) = g^{n+m} = g^n g^m$ and the last equality holds because $G$ is abelian. But in the general case, we can't use that homomorphism.

What data is needed in order to completely determinate an homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to an arbitrary group $G$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you do that in the non-abelian case?

Comment: Because g^{n+m} = g^n g^m only holds if G is abelian

Comment: $g^{n+m} = g^n g^m$ holds in every group.

Comment: Can you give an example where that does not hold?

Comment: my mistake. I mean, (gh)^m = g^m h^m only hold if $G$ is abelian

Comment: I find it quite extraordinary that you know what an endomorphism of a functor is and at the same time are confused by this :-|

Comment: @HeMan Your last comment is right, but you don't need that.

Comment: While $(gh)^m = g^m h^m$ in general only holds if $G$ is abelian, this is not a problem here. As said in my answer, the image of $1$ always determines the morphism completely, since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a free abelian group, and $1$ is a generator. Note that the same holds for $-1$, since it is also a generator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always enough to know the image of $1$ under that homomorphism, since by the homomorphism property one always has
$$
\phi \left( 2 \right) = \phi \left( 1 +  1 \right) = \phi \left( 1 \right) \phi \left( 1 \right) = g*g = g^2.$$

Note that if $\phi \left( 1 \right) = g$, the image $\phi \left( \mathbb{Z} \right) = \left\langle g \right\rangle$. Therefore the image is always a cyclic abelian subgroup.

Comment: Btw, this implies that the set $\mathrm{Hom} \left( \mathbb{Z}, G \right) \cong G$ as set (not an isomorphism of groups) with the bijection $$\phi \mapsto \phi \left( 1 \right).$$

Comment: Aren't they even isomorphic as groups if you use point-wise multiplication in Hom$(\mathbb{Z},G)$?

Comment: @Bemte: As pointed out in the comments to the question, if $f,g$ are group homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z} \to G$, there is no reason why the map $n \mapsto f(n) g(n)$ should be a group  homomorphism; in fact, it's a group homomorphism if and only if $f(1)$ and $g(1)$ commute.